# VS2010 Internal compiler error on Qt lambda expressions containing function calls with default parameters?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, lambda, default-parameters

VC++ Compiler crashes on the following code snippet:

```
class MyClass : public QObject {
   public:
   void onFinished(std::function<void(const QMap<QString, QVariant> &args)> cb) ;
   // ...
}

MyClass *request;
// ...
request->onFinished([] (const QMap<QString, QVariant> &args) -> void {
   QVariant c = args.value("valid");
});
```

Console output says "...fatal error C1001: Interner Compilerfehler."

Actually Qt's [QMap::value](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#value) is defined as

```
const T value(const Key & key, const T & defaultValue = T()) const
```

and when I pass in the second argument like

```
QVariant c = args.value("valid", QVariant());
```

is works! Any ideas? Are there some VC++ Hotfixes targeting this issue?

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2010 (10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel)
- Qt 5.1.1

Comment: You're expecting lambdas to work with VS 2010? That's optimistic.

Comment: @Columbo according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) VC10 support version 1.0 of lambdas.